# open with mode 'ab' got FileNotFoundError (No such file or directory)

Tags: python, linux, filesystems

I know there is a lot of `No such file or directory` error. But I think this one is different.

It's easy to understand when the file was not existed and opened with normal mode read or write, or the intermediate directory is not existed.

But I got this when using **append** mode and the filename is a relative filename **without /** in the middle (it contains unicode characters).

I got the error from log file and I cannot reproduce it with same filename.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'A01_UE需求设计_V1_1_20211013160004'
  ... other call stack
  File "pkg/xxx.py", line 304, in download
    with open(file_name, 'ab') as f:
```

Other info:

```
os: ubuntu 16.04
kernel: 4.4.0-116-generic
python: version 3.8
filesystem: ext4 on lvm
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.

I struggled with the `open(f, 'ab')` but never found any problem.

I have a sudden idea this morning. Maybe someone changed `cwd`. And I searched in the project and found it. Someone wrote code like following

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
    os.chdir(tmpdir)
```

This code changed the working dir and did not restore it. The tmpdir got removed since it was created in `with` context.

And I cannot reproduce it because above code is in handler of another api request.